# How to get records in specific time range when the time range is between two days

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to query a specific range of time:

- i.e. 1/1/2021 - 1/31/2021
- between 5:55AM - 5:00AM (next day) for all days in above date

Comment: Do you need to extract this time frame for all the dates within date range?

Comment: @astentx: Yes .

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract time portion from your timestamps (`datetime` type for T-SQL) and filter by them in addition to dates filter.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=bdc7e9653787360dd7811bbf81007596)*

```
declare
  @dt_from datetime
  , @dt_to datetime
  , @tm_from time
  , @tm_to time
  , @dt datetime
;
  
select
  @dt = convert(datetime, '2021-02-10 11:48:36', 120)
  , @dt_from = convert(date, '2021-02-01', 23)
  , @dt_to = convert(date, '2021-02-28', 23)
  , @tm_from = convert(time, '05:55:00', 120)
  , @tm_to = convert(time, '05:00:00', 120)
;

with a as (
  select @dt as dt union all
  select dateadd(hour, 20, @dt) union all
  select dateadd(hour, -15, @dt) union all
  select dateadd(hour, -6, @dt) union all
  select dateadd(day, -30, @dt) union all
  select convert(datetime, '2021-02-01 00:01:02', 120) union all
  select convert(datetime, '2021-02-28 20:01:02', 120)
)
select *
from dt
/*Restrict dates*/
where dt >= @dt_from
  and dt < dateadd(day, 1, @dt_to)
  and (
    /*Exclude time intervals between 05:00 and 05:55*/
    cast(dt as time) <= @tm_to
    or cast(dt as time) >= @tm_from
  )
```

Or if you need only the cases when entire time frame falls into your dates (e.g. exclude times from 00:00 till 05:00 for start date and from 05:55 till 23:59:59 of end date):

```
select *
from dt
where dt between @dt_from and @dt_to
  and (
    /*Exclude time intervals between 05:00 and 05:55*/
    cast(dt as time) <= @tm_to
    or cast(dt as time) >= @tm_from
  )
  /*Exclude time intervals at boundary dates*/
  and not(
    (cast(dt as date) = @dt_from and cast(dt as time) <= @tm_to)
    or (cast(dt as date) = @dt_to and cast(dt as time) >= @tm_from)
  )
```